# Programmatically add value to multi-valued/repeater field at weight/index

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

In Drupal 8, I have a content type and more than a few nodes that have a Paragraph field with unlimited number of values, and so I need to programmatically add a paragraph at an index to the existing values in the field. I know in the form editor widget I'm able to add a field value then drag the field to the order that I need, or change the weight then save the content.

I'm currently loading the node and appending the value like so

```
    $paragraph_node = Paragraph::create($fields);
    $paragraph_node->save();

    $node = Node::load($nid);

    $node->field_paragraph_repeater->appendItem(
      [
        'target_id' => $paragraph_node->id(),
        'target_revision_id' => $paragraph_node->getRevisionId(),
      ]
    );

    $node->save();
```

but this only adds the value at the end, how would I be able to add this with a weight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the field values as an array and then use [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to insert your new value where you want it. See [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797526/6335551).

```
$values = $node->get('field_paragraph_repeater')->getValue();
$addition = [
  'target_id' => $paragraph_node->id(),
  'target_revision_id' => $paragraph_node->getRevisionId(),
];
$addition_index = 3;

// Insert the new value into your $values array.
array_splice($values, $addition_index, 0, [$addition]);

// Set the value on your node and save.
$node->set('field_paragraph_repeater', $values);
$node->save();
```